# If f is completely continuous, then I-f is proper

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. $f:X\to X$ is defined to be completely continuous when $\overline{f(B)}$ is compact whenever $B$ is a bounded set of X.

I want to show that $I-f$ is proper, that means, if $K\subset X$ is compact, then $(I-f)^{-1}(K)$ is also compact.

My attempt:

Since normed spaces are metric spaces, compactness and sequential compactness are equivalent.

Let $K\subset X$ be compact.

Let $(x_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence in $(I-f)^{-1}(K)$. I want to show that it has a convergent subsequence. We have that $(I-f)(x_{n})$ is a sequence in $K$, which is compact, then there is a convergent subsequence $(I-f)(x_{n_{k}})\rightarrow x$. (*)

Also, since $f$ is completely continuous, ***we have that $\overline{f\{(x_{n_{k}}): k\in \mathbb{N}\}}$ is compact***. Since $f(x_{n_{k}})\in \overline{f\{(x_{n_{k}}): k\in \mathbb{N}\}}$, for all k, there is another convergent subsequence $f(x_{n_{k_{l}}})\rightarrow y$.

But from (*) we can say that $(I-f)(x_{n_{k_{l}}})\rightarrow x$

Since $(I-f)(x_{n_{k}})=x_{n_{k}}-f(x_{n_{k}})$, I can show that $x_{n_{k_{l}}}\rightarrow x+y$, and then we are done, since $(x_{n_{k_{l}}})_{l}$ is a convergent subsequence of our initial sequence.

However, in order for the bold text to be correct, I have to show that $\{(x_{n_{k}}): k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded. I know that $(I-f)(x_{n_{k}})$ is bounded, but this doesn't seem to help. Is there a way to show this boundedness?

Is there a different approach to prove the statement?

Comment: The claim is clearly wrong since $I-f$ need not be injective. It has, however, a finite-dimensional kernel. *Fredholm theory* is the magic word to google.

Comment: Why is the claim wrong? I-f being proper would imply injectivity?

Comment: For an example, let $X=\ell^2$ be the space of all square summable sequences and define $f((x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N})=(x_1,0,0,\cdots)$. $f$ is completely continuous but $I-f$ is not proper, its kernel $(I-f)^{-1}(\{0\})$ is the one-dimensional subspace generated by $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ which is not compact.

Comment: Oh, I see it, thank you!